# Is there a stratified enum, or base class for enum in C++?

Tags: c++, enums

I encountered a situation where I need to write many enums, but wish to separate, or stratify all the enums into groups of enums of smaller length, as the following shows:

```
enum class health {HP,Shield};
enum class battle {STR,AGL,INT};

// such struct DOESN'T WORK, either with instantiated object or direct struct referencing
struct hero_num{
    enum class health {HP,Shield};
    enum class battle {STR,AGL,INT};
};
```

The reason I am writing a `struct` to hold all enums is that I want to use all those enums by only referencing the `hero_num` type, so as to utilize functions as such:

```
// A class definition scope
{
...
    int get_stats(hero_num stats_type);
    void add_stats(hero_num stats_type, int value);
...
};

// I wish to call all the enum with ONE definition
void add_stats(health::HP,100);
void add_stats(battle::STR,10);
```

I am not sure whether aggregating declared `enum` into `struct`, or create a base class `enum` for all `enum` would work as intended. How should I design my structure to make such a function call? Or, in general, **how could I break a lengthy `enum` into smaller `enum`s, and make the right type reference?**

Comment: Possibly hack something with each enum having a NUL type enumeration, then create multiple 1 parm ctor of your struct that take the different enum types, initializing the specified one, but setting the "other" one to the NUL type???  EDIT: forgot to mention you need member vars of the various enum types.

Comment: I'm curious as to what approach you've selected from the different approaches you've considered.

Comment: I don't have many options in my head to consider. The merit I know to use `enum` is to limit the ranges of input to choose from by users. I think I will stick to `enum` solution so long as it doesn't draw serious system defect, but be open to other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to ask yourself if you need enums, particularly, or if you actually just want some kind of tag. Enums allow runtime switching based on an object of the enum type, whereas for the use case you've shown (`health::HP`, `battle::STR`) the property type is known at compile time, and a type-based tag approach may suffice.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct health {
    struct HP{};
    struct Shield{};
};

struct battle {
    struct STR{};
    struct AGL{};
    struct INT{};
};

struct hero_num : health, battle {};
// hero_num::HP
// hero_num::Shield
// hero_num::STR
// hero_num::AGL
// hero_num::INT

struct hero {
    template<typename property>
    void add_stats(int value) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<property, hero_num::HP>) {
            hp += value;
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<property, hero_num::Shield>) {
            shield += value;
        }
        // ... and so on
    }

  private:
    int hp{};
    int shield{};
    int strenght{};
    int agility{};
    int intelligence{};
};

int main() {
    hero my_hero{};
    my_hero.add_stats<hero_num::HP>(12);
}
```

Comment: This looks a good solution system-wise. Gonna spend sometime dig into details. A good design, I suppose.

Comment: The `constexpr` you used is very much like the `hasattr()` in Python. Do you have any ideas on how can I write the same functionalities as `setattr()`, 'getattr()' in C++? They essentially, modify or access data members of class object in Python.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a better hack but i would use the enum underlying type as a base type for function calls like this :

```
enum health {
    HP = 0,
    Shield = 1
};
enum battle {
    STR = Shield + 1,
    AGL,
    INT
};

void add_stats(int stats_type, int value); // underlying type is int
int get_stats(int stats_type);
```

and then call it as you wanted :

```
    add_stats(health::HP, 100);
    add_stats(battle::STR, 10);
```

I use `enum` in this example because i found it easier to write here. You can actually do the same with C++11 and `enum class`, but you'll need to *static_cast* to the enum underlying type.

Comment: I will give it a try as it seems a decent way to process the issue based on insistence on `enum`. I use `enum class` simply because it would not contaminate the name on other vars, i.e. I can no longer name a `health` int variable.

Comment: You can declare your enums inside a specific namespace if you don't want to contaminate the global namespace.